# Is Django using any front end framework or library?

Tags: django, frontend

Is Django Admin validated their data to client side or server side ?

And when we using Django Forms then is still need to use front end framework  for data validations ?

Comment: Since you can see that the other question was closed for being off-topic, what made you think you should ask another off-topic question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No other question was related to Ajax best library , asked 10 years ago and active 4 years 11 months now in 2019 we have multiple options to select front end framework and Ajax best library is my one point from above mentioned list.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This is not only the one point, i asked two other questions related to front end framework   
 Is Django Admin validated their data to client side or server side ? And when we using Django Forms then is still need to use front end framework for data validations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Django using jQuery library and for custom validations we can use jQuery to validate data.

Here are some links

[Add jQuery in django admin site](http://kennethjiang.blogspot.com/2016/02/jquery-in-django-admin-site.html)

[Adding inlines using of custom jQuery](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/adding-jquery-event-listeners-to-dynamically-creat/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you use Dajgno-rest-Framework and if you want the front-end Framework to have all those things, then the ideal would be Angular, from version 2 onwards:
Ajax calls: HttpModule or from version 6 HttClient.
It helps you reuse components.
It facilitates the validation of forms (With html5)
Structure code, quite clean.
Animations, if the framework covers it.

Otherwise, django's own template system offers many advantages to work, you can combine using Jquery. If you use Angular Js (Old version) you should be careful with possible conflicts, for example in the interpolation of double braces {{}}.